# Neo4j out of memory exception when creating relationships via Neo4J Browser

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

```
MATCH (a:PARENT), (b:CHILD) WHERE a.id = b.id MERGE (b)-[:PART_OF]->(a)
```

I am running the above Neo4J query but I run into a memory exception, "the transaction size reached"

I updated the value of `db.memory.transaction.max` to 2g but I faced the same error when I tried to create a relationship among nodes of 2 labels.
I am using Neo4j 5.17 community edition in a docker container, label A contains around 150K nodes and B contains around 280K nodes.

Can the above relationship creation be done in batches using apoc.periodic.iterate?

My machine has 16GB ram, what value should db.memory.transaction.max be set to for good performance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`CALL IN TRANSACTIONS OF x ROWS`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/subqueries/subqueries-in-transactions/) method to commit periodically after the desired `x` amount of rows

```
MATCH (a:PARENT), (b:CHILD) WHERE a.id = b.id 
WITH a, b
CALL {
    WITH a, b
    MERGE (b)-[:PART_OF]->(a)
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 50_000 ROWS
```

Comment: Why do we need 2 WITH? I am new to cypher but with just make a,b the only variables in the query right?

Comment: the first WITH is needed to break from a MATCH clause to a CALL clause, the WITH inside the subquery is needed to imported variables from the outer scope to the inner scope.

Comment: The first `WITH` is not actually needed in that query.